# How to normalize and standardscaler to string data

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, sklearn-pandas

how can i do normalize() or StandardScaler() if the data is still in string format?
is the parameter need to be tfidf? and how can i manually transform string to tfidf when im not use pipeline ?
i got error like this:
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'お気に入り の Ubuntu : 無償 OS & amp ; 無償 ソフト で 何 でも 揃う ! : 10 . 04 LTS 日本語 Remix 版'

after i called

```
 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
                                      df.body_wakati,  #data
                                      y,  #here the y is classification
                                      test_size=0.2,
                                      random_state=10,
                                      shuffle=True
)
```

X_train is string
[image]

edit:
[code](https://ideone.com/QDfkb4)

Comment: can you show the dataframe

Comment: @Kenan  i added the code see my edit dataframe is df

Answer (score 1):

You can't standard scale or normalize string data, you can only do that to numbers. For most common algorithms you need to turn your string data into numbers somehow so that you can use them in your algorithm. It's not clear to me what your text is. If it is a limited number of predefined inputs you could treat it as a categorical variable and one-hot-encode it. If it's more like free text you'll need to use the methods of natural language processing (NLP). This is a large field, but an introduction can be found [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/machine-learning-text-processing-1d5a2d638958).

Comment: as you can see the code in my edit, i already know and changed the word to tf-idf but usually i use pipeline. is there way to convert data to tf-idf but not use pipeline?

Comment: Sorry I didn't read that part of the question properly. You can run it manually, see e.g. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#text-feature-extraction

Comment: i use this to get the tf-idf but x_train still have some string word on it. this this step right? count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(df.body_wakati)
tf_transformer = TfidfTransformer(use_idf=False).fit(X_train_counts)
X_train_tf = tf_transformer.transform(X_train_counts)                                                 for the x_test is the code same or is it only transform without fit?